# How the problem of dark silicon is/will be solved?

Tags: transistors, power-dissipation

I read in [this article](http://futurismic.com/2011/08/02/dark-silicon-an-end-to-moores-law/) that within a couple of years about 21% of transistors will have to be switched off some time, else the chip will cross its limit of heat dissipation.

What general techniques (at the microarchitectural level and above) are already being implemented to address this problem and what techniques have been proposed for possible future implementation?

Comment: You ask us to solve one of the biggest obstacles in contemporary chip design??

Comment: @WoutervanOoijen I think a high-level overview of how the problem is being addressed is possible.  E.g., multicore (especially heterogenous) and accelerators.  Dark silicon indicates that transistors are so cheap in area while expensive in power that specialized function (which increases energy efficiency) is attractive even when not fully utilized.

Comment: @PaulA.Clayton, thanks for editing, and presenting your views

Answer (score 1):

You (or more precisely, the New York Times) assume that this is not happening now!

Today we employ a large number of ways to reduce power consumption.  They include:  Turning off the clock to certain circuits, varying the clock frequency, varying the voltage used to power to certain circuits, and turning off power certain circuits entirely.  This is done on many levels.  In larger systems, this might be done at the rack, box, or PCB level.  But it is also done at the chip level and also the subsystem within a chip level.

Normally this is done to reduce power, for reduced power's sake.  But sometimes, today, it is done to reduce heat.  For example, some CPU's have an on-chip temperature sensor and when the chip gets too hot the main clock frequency and/or voltage is reduced to bring the temperature back within limits.

The granularity that this is done keeps getting smaller.  Meaning, that the section of the circuit that is controlled, individually, keeps getting smaller.  This is simply due to the designers of these chips getting better, and the design tools also getting better.

That article has not unveiled anything "newsworthy" here.  The headline could have just as easily been rewritten as:  "Someone invokes Moores Law, Again, to justify a research paper".  Or slightly less sarcastically as:  "Engineers learn, build on what they did last week".

"Dark Silicon" is something we've been doing today, and will do better tomorrow.  Yawn.